# Python and landscape_api

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04

I am working on managing Canonical CM Landscape through Python api's. I don't know if any one could help me but am stuck in one point and I don't know if it is a simple Python error of that specific library. This is part of larger script but it drops when I tried to use the last function in this listing.

```
    import os, json, sys, subprocess, csv, datetime, time
    from landscape_api.base import API, HTTPError
    from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT,call


    uri = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    api = API(uri, key, secret)

    proc=Popen('zenity --entry --text "Fill with machine Tag to be searched" --entry-      text "Type Tag"', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, ) #Input from zenity window
    output=proc.communicate()[0] 
    user="root"
    script="2408"
    mac = api.execute_script(query="tag:%s", script_id="script_id:%s", username="user:%s" %(output, script, user))
```

Last function api.execute_script returns error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "Python_MAC_IP.py", line 35, in <module>
       mac = api.execute_script(query="tag:%s", script_id="script_id:%s", username="user:%s" %(output, script, user))
       TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: The `%` operator works on a single string and a tuple of replacements, not every string on the same line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use the `%` operator on a single string, not across multiple strings. What you are currently asking Python to do is insert multiple variables into a string that only has one defined.

Change this line:

```
mac = api.execute_script(query="tag:%s", script_id="script_id:%s", username="user:%s" %(output, script, user))
```

to this:

```
mac = api.execute_script(query="tag:%s" %tag, script_id="script_id:%s" %script, username="user:%s" %user
```